# restrict the input Number box with value range

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I restrict the input number box  with 1-10 integer part and 0-59 decimal part. If  the user enter the value 11.00 or 2.60 or 0 should not be allowed . How can restrict the integer part and decimal part of the value ?

```
<input type="number"   class="form-control format-text emphrs" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs"  />
```

Comment: Hi @AlanPauil,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like following:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control format-text emphrs" oninput="validate(this)" id="number" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs"/>
<div id="error" class="text-danger"></div>
@section Scripts
{ 
<script>
    var validate = function (e) {
        var t = e.value;
        e.value = (t.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (t.substr(0, t.indexOf(".")) + t.substr(t.indexOf("."), 3)) : t;
    }
    $("#number").keyup(function () {
        var x = parseFloat($("#number").val());
        var a = Math.floor(x);
        var b = (x % 1).toFixed(2).substring(2);
        var c = (a + 0.59).toFixed(2);
        $("#error").empty();
        if (b > 59) {
            $("#number").val(c);
            $("#error").text("Please enter with 0-59 decimal part")
        }
        if (a > 10) {
            $("#number").val(10);
            $("#error").text("Please enter with 1-10 integer part")
        }
        if (a <1) {
            $("#number").val(1);
            $("#error").text("Please enter with 1-10 integer part")
        }
    })
</script>
}
```